# Any ANSPs uses stack controllers?

Tags: air-traffic-control

The stack controller only controls one or two stack and release aircraft accordingly. Does any ANSP (air navigation service provider) provide this service?

Comment: Not so common acronyms should be spelled out at least once.

Comment: In the U.S. I've never heard the terms ANSP or stack controller.  If you are asking about aircraft in a holding pattern perhaps the terms are used in a country other than U.S.  Could you clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Airborne holdings are usually handled by ACC or approach sectors, typically manned by ACS or APS rated controllers respectively. There is no separate rating for "stack controllers" as you call them.